# Can we use await and same functions for promises?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, if-statement

So i have request coming based on that i am building `this.request` array so i can make calls to urls and request.body that is pushed into array , In below code trying to use `RequestResponseHandler.processRequest` for both promises but its always going into spec(duplicate call)  when i call same function `processRequest` for other promise , How can i make sure if `processRequest` is called for `spec` ignore that if condition and go to `PTM`

request

```
{ header: { lineOfBusiness: ["spec","PTM"] } , body: data }
```

handler.ts

```
    export class RequestResponseHandler {
        public static processRequest(data: any, url: string): Promise < any > {
            const reqObject: IRequestURL = {}
            as IRequestURL;
            const lob = data.header.lineOfBusiness;
            if (lob[0] === "spec") {
                const specUrl = urlConfig + url;
                reqObject.url = specUrl;
                reqObject.body = data;
            }
            if (lob[1] === "PTM") {
                const ptmUrl = urlConfig + url;
                reqObject.url = ptmUrl;
                reqObject.body = data;
            }
         return Promise.resolve(reqObject);
        }
    }
```

controllet.ts

```
     const bRetSpec: boolean = await this.specBalanceRequest(request);
            const bRetPtm: boolean = await this.ptmBalanceRequest(request);

 if (!bRetPtm && !bRetSpec) {
            return Promise.reject(new Error("Processing failed"));
        }
        try {
            const __data: IResponse = await makeRequest(this._request);
            const resp1 = await another promise to resolve _data[0];
            const resp2 = await another promise to resolve _data[1];
            return await Promise.all([resp1, resp2]);
        } catch (err) {
            return Promise.reject(err);
        }

        private async specBalanceRequest(@Body() request: ExpressRequest): Promise < boolean > {
            const specUrl = "/payments";
            const reqObject = await RequestResponseHandler.processRequest(request.body, specialtyUrl);
            this._request.push(reqObject);
            return Promise.resolve(true);
        }

        private async ptmBalanceRequest(@Body() request: any): Promise < boolean > {
            const careURL = "/Order";
            const reqObject = await RequestResponseHandler.processRequest(request.body, careURL);
            this._request.push(reqObject);
            return Promise.resolve(true);
        }
```

Comment: What are you doing with the `reqObject` that you create?

Comment: What is `data.header.lineOfBusiness`, there's no `.header` in your sample request? Also it's an array not a string - where do you want to do the looping?

Comment: i am passing it to another function like makeRequest where i am calling axios.all for the objects passed to it.

Comment: @Bergi i fixed the question the way request is coming

Comment: OK, still that `const lob = ["spec","PTM"]` will neither `=== "spec"` nor `=== "PTM"`. And where and how are you calling `makeRequest`?

Comment: `processRequest` doesn't appear to `return` anything?

Comment: added some more code to controller.ts to understand output i am looking

Comment: @Bergi process.Request is returning `Promise.resolve(reqObject)` problem is when i call processRequest for second response its adding spec url twice

Comment: Now both of your if statements will succeed every time `processRequest` is called, so of course it always writes the second url in the new request object. What you really need is to have `specBalanceRequest` add a request object with the `specUrl` when the `lob` array *contains* `"spec"`, and have `ptmBalanceRequest` add a request object with the `ptmUrl` when the `lob` array *contains* `"ptm"`. Do not use the same `processRequest` function - it's pretty useless. Also, don't use promises here! Nothing of what you are doing is actually asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I suggest is to not make unnecessary promise function. Keep it simple as possible.

`RequestResponseHandler.processRequest` doesn't need to be a promise

```
export class RequestResponseHandler {
  public static processRequest(data: any, url: string): IRequestURL {
    const reqObject: IRequestURL = {} as IRequestURL;
    const lob = data.header.lineOfBusiness;

    // I guess we can improve code below, no diff between "spec" and "ptm"
    if (lob[0] === "spec") {
      const specUrl = urlConfig + url;
      reqObject.url = specUrl;
      reqObject.body = data;
    }
    if (lob[1] === "PTM") {
      const ptmUrl = urlConfig + url;
      reqObject.url = ptmUrl;
      reqObject.body = data;
    }
    return reqObject; // return value not a promise
  }
}
```

in controller file

```
const bRetSpec: boolean = this.specBalanceRequest(request); // remove `await`
const bRetPtm: boolean = this.ptmBalanceRequest(request); // remove `await`

if (!bRetPtm && !bRetSpec) {
  return Promise.reject(new Error("Processing failed"));
}
try {
  const __data: IResponse = await makeRequest(this._request);
  // the two promise calls, I guess can be move to be inside promise.all
  return await Promise.all([anotherPromiseData0, anotherPromiseData1]);
} catch (err) {
  return Promise.reject(err);
}

// make it non promise
private specBalanceRequest(@Body() request: ExpressRequest): void {
  const specUrl = "/payments";
  const reqObject = RequestResponseHandler.processRequest(request.body, specialtyUrl);
  this._request.push(reqObject);
}

// make it non promise
private ptmBalanceRequest(@Body() request: any): void {
  const careURL = "/Order";
  const reqObject = RequestResponseHandler.processRequest(request.body, careURL);
  this._request.push(reqObject);
}
```